# 2012 Ford Escape Brake Grinding/Crunch Noise

Tags: ford, brakes, noise, escape, grinding

I have a 2012 Ford Escape that is a front wheel drive, which recently started to make a grinding sound when braking. The brakes are brand new, less than 10,000km. My brakes used to make a horrible grinding noise and then I replaced the front pads and rotors. The grinding stopped but has started to come back when I brake at slow speeds (under 20km/h), it’s more frequent after extended periods of driving. Everyone is at a loss to the noise. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had them all inspected? A test drive would be ideal. Also, have you had the back brakes examined? Because the issue may be dissrelated to the recent work.

Comment: It’s been inspected by both Ford as well as my personal mechanic. Both said the brakes are perfect. Back brakes are drums and have passed inspections as well.

Comment: Do you notice it more when you're braking in a straight line or turning? Or is it consistent in how it acts?

Comment: It’s more when at slow speeds (ie right before a stop) in a straight line. It worsen after I’ve been driving for extended periods, over an hour.

Comment: But no difference when turning and braking vs straight and braking?